# zsh function wrapping grep output only returns a few lines

Tags: shell, scripting, zsh

I'm trying to create a small zsh function that allows me to grep my history - `hgrep test` should return every command i've typed that containts `test`.

on my machine it only returns about 6 results. when i type `history | grep test` i get a *lot* more results. what gives?

```
hgrep (){
     history | grep $1
}
```

the output - this is complete!

```
➜  ~ hgrep test
 7887  mkd test
 7889  rm -r test
 7894  hgrep test
 7896  history | grep test
```

this is incomplete output. also, notice that the first results are *much* earlier

```
➜  ~ history | grep test
  252  cp mgroup /test
  254  cp mgroup /test
  322  vi test.js
  324  node test.js
  325  vi test.js
...
```

---

after some poking around it appears that the difference in behavior is related to when .zshrc is sourced. on new terminal i see the unwanted behavior. if i then `source ~/.zshrc` it works.

however, i'm still confused why this would happen.

Comment: where did you define hgrep ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your `history` command is `alias`ed to something else (for example `fc -l 1`) after the definition of the `hgrep` function.

So, you could put the `hgrep` function definition after the `alias` setups.
Or, you could define the `hgrep` function (and any functions) which will not be affected with aliases, shell options etc.

TL;DR

The command `history` lists the last 16 events by default.

> `history`
>
> same as `fc -l`.
>   […]
>   `fc -l ... [ first [ last ] ]`
>
> If *first* is not specified, it will be set to -1 (the most recent event), or to -16 if the -l flag is given.
>
> -- [`zshbuiltins(1)` Shell Builtin Commands `fc`, `history`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-fc)

And aliases are checked and expanded at the read time.

> Every eligible word in the shell input is checked to see if there is an
>   alias defined for it.  If so, it is replaced by the text of  the  alias
>   if it is in command position
>   […]
>   aliases are expanded when the code is read in; the entire line is read in one go
>
> -- [`zshmisc(1)` Aliasing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Aliasing)

It seems that the`hgrep` function uses the shell-builtin command `history` which shows only a few events and the results may differ with using `history` (which is an `alias` to something else) interactively.

The `hgrep` function will be redefined by `source ~/.zshrc`, the `history` in that function will be expanded/replaced to the `alias` at this point.
You could check the resulting function by issuing the below command:

```sh
% functions hgrep
hgrep () {
…
(hgrep function's definition will be shown)
```

Answer (score 0):

The commands do something completely different.

```
 history | grep test
```

list all history events containing the string `test`.

```
history test
```

goes back in history to the most recent command starting with the string `test`, and lists all subsequent commands.

Comment: my question does not pertain to the result of `history test` - its not present in my question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake. Now I see it. But in your case, both (using the hgrep function and doing the grep manually) **must** produce the same result. Could you run both variants again, but with `set -x` enable, and post the output? Maybe the `hgrep` you are calling is not the `hgrep` which you *think* you are calling.

Comment: i'm confused about your suggestion to `set -x`, could you clarify?

adding output to original post

Comment: Setting `-x` would display the actual commands executed; this would show, whether you are really executing the hgrep version you think you are running. BTW, you are running both commands in the *same* bash process, aren't you? I'm asking, because the history numbers differ so much.

Comment: ah, i'm learning!

`set -x` didn't reveal much to me, but i discovered something in the process.

my `hgrep` function works fine if i source my .zshrc file manually. it works improperly on initial terminal load. its a step, but i'm still baffled.